# SIGSEGV when using pthreads in Stop-and-Wait Protocol implementation

Tags: linux, sockets, pthreads

I'm a college student and as part of a Networks Assignment I need to do an implementation of the Stop-and-Wait Protocol. The problem statement requires using 2 threads. I am a novice to threading but after going through the man pages for the pthreads API, I wrote the basic code. However, I get a segmentation fault after the thread is created successfully (on execution of the first line of the function passed to pthread_create() as an argument).

```
typedef struct packet_generator_args
{
    int max_pkts;
    int pkt_len;
    int pkt_gen_rate;
} pktgen_args;

/* generates and buffers packets at a mean rate given by the
pkt_gen_rate field of its argument; runs in a separate thread  */
void *generate_packets(void *arg)
{
    pktgen_args *opts = (pktgen_args *)arg; // error occurs here
    buffer = (char **)calloc((size_t)opts->max_pkts, sizeof(char *));
    if (buffer == NULL)
        handle_error("Calloc Error");
    //front = back = buffer;
    ........

    return 0;
}
```

The main thread reads packets from this bufffer and runs the stop-and wait algorithm.

```
pktgen_args thread_args;
thread_args.pkt_len = DEF_PKT_LEN;
thread_args.pkt_gen_rate = DEF_PKT_GEN_RATE;
thread_args.max_pkts = DEF_MAX_PKTS;

/* initialize sockets and other data structures */
.....
pthread_t packet_generator;
pktgen_args *thread_args1 = (pktgen_args *)malloc(sizeof(pktgen_args));
memcpy((void *)thread_args1, (void *)&thread_args, sizeof(pktgen_args));
retval = pthread_create(&packet_generator, NULL, &generate_packets, (void *)thread_args1);
if (retval != 0)
    handle_error_th(retval, "Thread Creation Error");
.....
/* send a fixed no of packets to the receiver wating for ack for each. If
the ack is not received till timeout occurs resend the pkt */
.....
```

I have tried debugging using gdb but am unable to understand why a segmentation fault is occuring at the first line of my `generate_packets()` function. Hopefully, one of you can help. If anyone needs additional context, the entire code can be obtained at http://pastebin.com/Z3QtEJpQ. I am in a real jam here having spent hours over this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize your `buffer` as `NULL`:

```
 char **buffer = NULL;
```

and then in `main()` without further do, you try to address it:

```
while (!buffer[pkts_ackd]); /* wait as long as the next pkt has not
```

Basically my semi-educated guess is that your thread hasn't generated any packets yet and you crash on trying to access an element in NULL.

```
[162][04:34:17] vlazarenko@alluminium (~/tests) > cc -ggdb -o pthr pthr.c 2> /dev/null
[163][04:34:29] vlazarenko@alluminium (~/tests) > gdb pthr
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1824) (Thu Nov 15 10:42:43 UTC 2012)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin"...Reading symbols for shared libraries .. done

(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/vlazarenko/tests/pthr 
Reading symbols for shared libraries +............................. done

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x000000010000150d in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbffb10) at pthr.c:205
205         while (!buffer[pkts_ackd]); /* wait as long as the next pkt has not
(gdb)
```

Comment: The main lesson is that the original poster should learn to use `gdb` and compile with `gcc -Wall -g`